# Laravel update role unique field in unique key table

Tags: laravel

I have a table 'employee' with no id, as Primary Key I use column `kode`.
I want to update phone (unique) with larval unique role:

```
'phone'   => 'required|numeric|digits_between:8,14|unique:employee,phone,' . $kode
```

when I tested it shows error `unknown column id`

please help, thanks!

Comment: for update you need id

Comment: what if there's no id in the table? can I use the role?

Comment: You should always use an unique identifier in the table. Usually this would be the ID column. What is the primary key for the employee table?

Comment: the pk is `kode` column

Comment: Did you change/set the `$primaryKey` in your model? `protected $primaryKey = 'kode';` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions, Section "Primary Keys"

Comment: @Sergio I don't think so. You'd need a primary key, which doesn't have to be `id`

Comment: @kerbholz yes I already did that too

Answer (score 1):

it solved. I just did this:

```
'phone'   => 'required|numeric|digits_between:8,14|unique:employee,phone,' . $kode.', kode'
```